# How can I make this Formik form work with custom Buttons I can't get the values to get to handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am learning React.js and I have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dashboard-forked-gw-sqt3r?file=/src/views/auth/LoginView.js) that is a a Material-Ui boilerplate. I try something now like I want the login Facebook `Button` when clicked to handle Facebook login.

I read the [Docs](https://formik.org/docs/overview) and can't see any explanation for this situation. Even the  [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dashboard-forked-gw-sqt3r?file=/src/views/auth/LoginView.js) Material-UI suggests this is a good approach.

[image]

This is what I have tried, it looks like this:

```
    <Formik
                                initialValues={{
                                    email: 'demo@devias.io',
                                    password: 'Password123',
                                    facebook: 'dddd',
                                }}
                                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                                    email: Yup.string().email('Must be a valid email').max(255).required('Email is required'),
                                    password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required'),
                                })}
                                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                                        setSubmitting(false);
                                    }, 400);
                                }}
                            >
                                {({ errors, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, touched, values }) => (
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                        <Box mb={3}>
                                            <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h2">
                                                Sign in
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom variant="body2">
                                                Sign in on the internal platform
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Box>
                                        <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                <Button
                                                    className={classes.Facebook}
                                                    fullWidth
                                                    startIcon={<FacebookIcon />}
                                                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                                                    size="large"
                                                    variant="contained"
                                                    name="facebook"
                                                    type="facebook"
                                                    value={values.facebook}
                                                >
                                                    SIGN in with Facebook
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
```

........

As you see on the image the:

```
<Button
    className={classes.Facebook}
    fullWidth
    startIcon={<FacebookIcon />}
    onClick={handleSubmit}
    size="large"
    variant="contained"
    name="facebook"
    type="facebook"
    value='sdsadadadsadada'
>
    SIGN in with Facebook
</Button>
```

I have the `type="facebook"` and `value='sdsadadadsadada` set but when I click the button the `onClick={handleSubmit}` does not show this values in the `handleSubmit` , it show the default values like:

[image]

What I want is to handle login depending on this tree types, Facebook, Google or email. Do I have to create a `Button` `onClick` separately for the Facebook and Google Buttons to handle this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/214#issuecomment-684040497).

Basically it looks like this:

```
function FormContainer(props) {
  const [formType, setFormType] = useState(DEFAULT_FORM_TYPE);

  const handlerSubmit = (methodX, methodY) => async values => {
    if (formType === FORM_TYPE_X) {
      return await methodX(values);
    }
    return await methodY(values);
  };

  const submitFormType = (formTypeSubmited, handleSumitType) => () => {
    setFormType(formTypeSubmited, () => handlerSubmit());
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={handlerSubmit(props.saveToApiMethodX, props.saveToApiMethodY)}
      validate={values => props.validate(formType, values)}
    >
      {(values, handleSubmit, errors) => (
        <>
        <button onClick={submitFormType(FORM_TYPE_X, handlerSubmit)}>
        Method X
        </button>
        <button onClick={submitFormType(FORM_TYPE_Y, handlerSubmit)}>
        Method Y
        </button>
        </>
        )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```